# jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2 (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException)

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, java-7, sslhandshakeexception

My code was working fine  with out any exception, i recently connected to a server , in my code i just changed the server host name, username and password. i got the following exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints
```

When i googled , i found that we have to change the file `Java\jre7\lib\security\java.security` i referred this link [click here](http://www.richardnichols.net/2012/08/arrrggh-java-security-cert-certificateexception-certificates-does-not-conform-to-algorithm-constraints/).

But if we develop a client application this solution is not good enough. Is there any better way to resolve this problem.

Any help is appreciable

Comment: There are good reasons to disable MD2. Is the server under your control? Just wondering which CA still issues certificates using MD2.

Comment: Unfortunately Server is not in our control

Comment: @Burno server using self signed certificate

Comment: So now you have two reasons to complain to them, not just one.